# UIOrientation returns 0 or 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

I am running a simple function that get's called in multiple areas to help deal with layout on an iPad app during orientation changes. It looks like this:

```
- (void) getWidthAndHeightForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    NSLog(@"New Orientation: %d",orientation);
end
```

And I call it in various places like this:

```
[self getWidthAndHeightForOrientation: [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]];
```

The function normally has some simple code that runs if the orientation is portrait or landscape. Unfortunately it wasn't working as expected when the app is started in what would be position 1. I get 0 as a result. Later if the function is called in the same manner but the device has never been rotated I get back a value of 5. What does this mean? Why would it throw these values?

In short why would [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] ever throw 0 or 5 instead of any value between 1 and 4?

**UPDATE:**

Because I kept finding bugs in my code due to the way orientation was handled, I wrote a definitive post on how to handle UIDevice or UIInterface orientations: http://www.donttrustthisguy.com/orientating-yourself-in-ios

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using `UIDeviceOrientationIsValidInterfaceOrientation(orientation)`

It will tell you if its a valid orientation (valid being either landscape or portrait, not FaceUp/FaceDown/UnKnown). Then you can treat it as if its portrait if its unknown.

This is how I do it:

```
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsValidInterfaceOrientation(interfaceOrientation) && UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)) {
    // handle landscape
} else {
    // handle portrait
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bob! I'l have to give that a try.

Answer (score 8):

Did you take a look at the enum values for `UIInterfaceOrientation`? From the docs:

```
typedef enum {
   UIDeviceOrientationUnknown,
   UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
   UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
   UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft,
   UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
   UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp,
   UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown
} UIDeviceOrientation;
```

So it could conceivably be anything from 0-6.

Edit: Maybe you should be using the methods on your `UIViewController` (`willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`, etc.) instead of calling `orientation` on the `UIDevice`?

Comment: Once I change the orientation by rotating the device it is always proper. But I don't understand why it would be Unknown or return FaceUp. Is there a function I need to call to have it find the orientation if it is currently unknown?

Comment: I assume that FaceUp is returned when the device is parallel to the ground and hasn't been rotated yet. (I edited my answer a little because apparently I can't count.)

Comment: I've edited my answer again after looking some stuff up. (I admit I mostly do desktop stuff.)

Comment: Thanks - I believe you are right. I've updated my code to assume the application is in portrait if unknown has been returned. This seems to have solved my dilemma.

Answer (score 0):

`[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation` returns a `UIDeviceOrientation`:

> The value of the property is a constant that indicates the current
>   orientation of the device. This value represents the physical
>   orientation of the device and may be different from the current
>   orientation of your application’s user interface.

Your `getWidthAndHeightForOrientation` function takes a `UIInterfaceOrientation` parameter:

> The orientation of the application's user interface.

These types, though related, are not the same thing.  You can access the current **interface orientation** from any view controller using `self.interfaceOrientation`. `UIInterfaceOrientation` has 4 possible values while `UIDeviceOrientation` has 9:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIDeviceOrientation) {
    UIDeviceOrientationUnknown,
    UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,            // Device oriented vertically, home button on the bottom
    UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,  // Device oriented vertically, home button on the top
    UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft,       // Device oriented horizontally, home button on the right
    UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,      // Device oriented horizontally, home button on the left
    UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp,              // Device oriented flat, face up
    UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown             // Device oriented flat, face down
};

// Note that UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft is equal to UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight (and vice versa).
// This is because rotating the device to the left requires rotating the content to the right.
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIInterfaceOrientation) {
    UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait           = UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
    UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown = UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
    UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft      = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
    UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight     = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft
};
```